# How to escape a character in a string in business central AL

Tags: escaping, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al, businesscentral

I keep coming across situations where i need to escape a character such as a quote. I never been able to figure out how to do this since a simple `Message('test \' test');` doesn't work.

Every time i need to figure out a workaround, and its starting to bother me. Is there a way to do this or is it simply impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a double quote mark in AL:

```
Message('test '' test');
```

Two consequent quote marks are interpreted as a single escaped quote. If you have a longer sequence, the same rule applies. `Message('''''Test''''');` will display the text with two quote marks on each side.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I think its a dumb way to do it but at least its functional... I guess